# Is $\exp$ the only function satisfying $f(x)=\displaystyle \int_{-x}^{+\infty} f(-t) dt$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, exponential-function

Today in class we first dealt with improper integrals, and as an example we found $ \displaystyle \int_0 ^{+\infty} e^{-x}dx=1$. Soon, I noticed that in fact $$e^x=\int_{-x}^{+\infty}e^{-t}dt. $$ Since I already know $\exp$ can be defined as the unique function such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$, I wondered whether this might be yet another way of defining it. In search of counterexamples, I rewrote the equation $$f(x) = \int_{-x}^{+\infty}f(-t)dt $$ as $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=f(x)-f'(x),$$ but still couldn't think of other solutions (besides $c \cdot e^x$ ). If there aren't, how to prove it?

**(this question arised from a terribly silly oversight)**

Answer (score 1):

Note that the functional equation
$$f(x) = \int\limits_{-x}^\infty f(-t)dt$$
implies that any (integrable) solution of this equation is differentiable (why?).
Then, by differentiating, you get
$$f^\prime(x) = f(x)$$

I leave it to you to continue the reasoning and fill any gaps you may suspect (note that you have still the freedom to assign an initial value).

Comment: Why doesn't this assume $f(-\infty)=0$?

Comment: Wait, could it be that we have $f(-\infty)=f(x)-f'(x)=f(x)-f'(x)$, or equivalently $f(-\infty)=-f(-\infty)$, whence $f(-\infty)=0$ and thus $f'=f$?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva $f(-\infty)=0$ isn't needed to get $f'=f$.

Comment: @Farnight Differentiating both sides of Thomas' first display, why shouldn't we get $f'(x)=f(x)-f(-\infty)$?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva No. If $F$ is a primitive of $f$, then $$f(x)=F(x)-F(-\infty)$$
So $$f'(x)=F'(x)=f(x) $$

Comment: @Farnight How does $F'(-\infty)$ disappear? I'm beginning to think this is a question I would have been able to answer after my next lesson.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva $F(-\infty)$ is constant. So its derivative is $0$.

Comment: @Farnight And that holds for any primitive? Am I forgetting something or we'll deal with that a little bit further in the topic of improper integrals, since we did not have much time today?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva It's not just because it's a primitive. The derivative of a constant function is $0$. So the derivative of $f(x)+c$ is $f'(x)+0=f'(x)$. Since $F(-\infty)$ is a constant, its derivative is also $0$. Are you familiar with the concept of a derivative?

Comment: @Farnight Yes, I am. I know the derivative of a constant is $0$, whence what you said. What I don't get is how we know $F(-\infty)$, and here is where I think I might be lacking something. Or, I'm forgetting something.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva $F(-\infty)$ is just the limit of $F$ at $-\infty$, which is a constant.

Comment: @Farnight Oh dear, that's what I was forgetting... what a shame, I'm so terribly gaga. Thanks Farnight, thank you all, +1 to both...

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is contnuous, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_{-x}^{+\infty}f(-t)\,\mathrm dt = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt =f(x)$$
Hence 
$$ f(x)=\int_{-x}^{+\infty}f(-t)\,\mathrm dt$$
is equivalent to $f'=f$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$. This would suit $f(x)=ce^x$ for any $c$.